# How to get distinct results with max of a field

Tags: postgresql, max, distinct

I have a query :

```
select distinct(donorig_cdn),cerhue_num_rfa,max(cerhue_dt) from t_certif_hue 


 group by donorig_cdn,cerhue_num_rfa 


 order by donorig_cdn
```

it returns me some repeated ids with different cerhue_num_rfa 
[image: 2451 2460 2467 are repeated]

how do i return only one line for the repeated ids with cerhue_num_rfa that matches the max of date (cerhue_dt) .. and have at the end only 10 results instead of 15 ?

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT** a  function. It is an operator that applies to **all** columns in the select list. `distinct (a), b, c` is exactly the same thing as `distinct a,(b),c` or `distinct a,b,(c)`. Having said that: you probably want `distinct on ()` instead. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Comment: It looks like a classic `top-n-per-group` problem.

Comment: Though it doesn't matter much for this small problem, it is best practice to enclude table definitions and sample data in the question. So, everyone can reproduce your behaviour and test their solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Postgres has [`SELECT DISTINCT ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) to the rescue. It only returns the first row found for each value of the given column. So, all you need is an order that ensures the latest entry comes first. No need for grouping.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (donorig_cdn) donorig_cdn,cerhue_num_rfa,cerhue_dt
  FROM t_certif_hue 
  ORDER BY donorig_cdn, cerhue_dt DESC;
```